# What are accepted characters sets in name fields in PassengerDetailsRQ?

Tags: sabre

What are accepted character sets in name fields in PassengerDetailsRQ?

I can't find relevant information about character sets in https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Passenger_Details/resources/

For example, umlaut characters complicate the issue and leaves me wondering if I need to force only latin characters.

From my testing, "-", ".", numbers are not allowed. The request fails with ".FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH" message.

I'm interested in the complete list of accepted character sets because I'm not sure what symbols can be entered in.

Answer (score 0):

Using UTF-8 would be correct, as no hyphens, numbers, umlauts, accent marks, apostrophes, or special characters like ñ.

Since PassengerDetails works following the same mandates native Sabre does, it might be useful checking the native Sabre help site, called Format Finder. For this situation in particular, you may [check here](https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/PassengerNameRecordPNR/PassengerNameRecordFields/NameFieldInPNR.aspx?ItemID=3596df4ec7c04666a60a18039ba51ab5&tabtype=format&documentId=3596df4ec7c04666a60a18039ba51ab5_format). (To login there, you can use the same credentials you use for creating sessions).

Comment: The PNR name field documentation has no information about the character limitation. So only alphabet characters without accents and spaces are allowed?

Comment: Spaces are accepted, but other "uncommon" characters are not.